# Return the column name of the first non-zero value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks as below:

```
name company count_2017 count_2018 count_2019 last_id
joe     abc     0           1         2         230283
cindy   bcd     0           0         3         239382
john    cde     1           1         0          238372
wang    def     0           0         3          1332
```

I put in code as:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.nonzero()[0][0]], axis=1)
```

This code will return the first non-zero value, however I am hoping to build a dataframe that returns the column name. The returned dataframe looks like below:

```
name count_2017 count_2018 count_2019  new_col
joe   0           1         2           2018
cindy 0           0         3           2019
john  1           1         0           2017
wang  0           0         3           2019
```

new_col = the column name (remove count_) of the first non-zero value. Is there anyway to edit from my existing code and return new_col?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
columns = df.select_dtypes(int).columns

df["new_col"] = (df.select_dtypes(int)
                 .gt(0)
                 .dot(columns.str[-4:] + " ")
                 .str.split()
                 .str[0])
df

    name    count_2017  count_2018  count_2019  new_col
0   joe         0           1           2       2018
1   cindy       0           0           3       2019
2   john        1           1           0       2017
3   wang        0           0           3       2019
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got an error "StopIteration: occurred at index 3". Probably because after name, I have another column, I changed the code to df.iloc[:, 2:5]. Do you know why I get the error

Comment: so your data does not exactly match what you shared

Comment: aEdited the code; see if it works for you @LearningCode

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame looks like:

```
    name  count_2017  count_2018  count_2019
0    joe           0           1           2
1  cindy           0           0           3
2   john           1           1           0
3   wang           0           0           3
```

Then:

```
df['new_col'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: next(c for v, c in zip(x, x.index) if v!=0).split('_')[-1], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name  count_2017  count_2018  count_2019 new_col
0    joe           0           1           2    2018
1  cindy           0           0           3    2019
2   john           1           1           0    2017
3   wang           0           0           3    2019
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got an error "StopIteration: occurred at index 3". Probably because after name, I have another column, I changed the code to df.iloc[:, 2:5]. Do you know why I get the error –

Comment: @LearningCode Probably you have some rows with all zeros. Can this situation happen? What should be result then?